# GetBindingExpression returns null in the Loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding-expressions

I'm trying to call the GetBindingExpression method in the Loaded event, but it always returns `null`.

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?  If it is expected, after what event do binding expressions become available?

I just create custom control

```
public partial class LookUp : ComboBox

public static readonly DependencyProperty LookUpItemsSourceProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.Register("LookUpItemsSource"
                           , typeof(IEnumerable)
                           , typeof(LookUp)
                           , new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsSourcePropertyChanged));


public IEnumerable LookUpItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetValue(LookUpItemsSourceProperty) as IEnumerable;
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(LookUpItemsSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }
```

And use this control in xaml

```
<Controls:LookUp Name="cb1"  LookUpItemsSource="{x:Static Helper:DataManager.CycleLookUpData}"
```

Now i want to get binding expression when control initialized that method return null:

```
cb1.GetBindingExpression(LookUp.LookUpItemsSourceProperty)
```

Comment: We can't help if you don't show us your code (XAML and corresponding code behind).

Comment: People, people!  Never ask for "source code."  Always ask for the ***minimum amount of code*** that covers the question.  In this case, we need to see the xaml for the control that has the binding you wish to retrieve (not the whole window!) and the Loaded event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x:static will set the value of key, it is not binding expression. You will have to use,

```
{Binding CycleLookUpData, source={x:static Helper:DataManager}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `{Binding ...` in XAML you can't use `GetBindingExpression()` method. In your case you set value instead of binding. You need to use `cb1.GetValue(LookUp.LookUpItemsSourceProperty)` instead.